# Error Doctrine Query when Using Group By

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm using Symfony Project 1.4 and Postgresql

I got error query in doctrine using

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
 ->select("count(sex) as total, sex")
 ->from('Biodata')
 ->groupBy('sex')           
 ->execute();
```

there is always display error like this when debug:

```
SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "e.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT e.id AS e__id, e.sex AS e__sex, COUNT(e.sex) AS e__0 ...
^. Failing Query: "SELECT e.id AS e__id, e.sex AS e__sex, COUNT(e.sex) AS e__0 FROM biodata e GROUP BY e.sex"
```

How to fix it and hide e.id column, is this bugs or need a trick?

Excepted result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine automatically add the primary key to the select list. We've got the same error using MSSQL.

Try to add not hydrate result:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
 ->setHydrationMode(Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_NONE)
 ->select("count(sex) as total, sex")
 ->from('Biodata')
 ->groupBy('sex')
 ->execute();
```

You won't have column name, but something like this I think:

```
+========+=========+
|   0    |    1    |
+========+=========+
|  183   |    1    |
+--------+---------+
|   54   |    2    |
+========+=========+
```

Comment: yea, but results is bad,
i need results just like this

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zsABU.png

Comment: ok thanks, it works, and i use --- Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc("select count(sex) as total, sex from biodata group by sex"); --- for more simple

Comment: This is another solution, less in a Doctrine way ;-) If my answer help you, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/182741) and upvote it, if you feel so.